# Get category by ID of child article - Joomla 2.5 API

Tags: api, joomla, joomla2.5

I have an ID of an article, and want to know it's parent category details.
To get category details by it's ID i've read an API that i need code like this:

```
 $categories = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Categories', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
 $categories->setState('filter.published', 1);
 $categories->setState('filter.access', $access);
 $items = $categories->getItems();
```

But this gives me (via [j-dump](https://github.com/mathiasverraes/jdump)) a list of objects not filtered at all. What setState filter i must apply to:
1) only one result 
2) filtered by category ID (visible in admin, not asset ID)= XX

And, if possible - how to get article's parent category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get a specific category like this:

```
$options    = array();
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content', $options);
$category   = $categories->get($article->catid);
```

From there you can use

```
$parent     = $category->getParent();
```

To get the parent category of the selected $category.

Update: To get the catid of the article, use this MySQL query:

```
SELECT `catid` FROM `#__content` WHERE `id` = $article_id
```

Comment: it is inside  a module, not component, so i don't have $article object, how i can get it in a module?

Comment: If you have the id of the article, you can query the database to get the catid of this article. I'm updating the answer with the query.

Comment: well you could get a table instance and load the row and get catid.